# How to filter case-insensitive on oneToOneField in django

Tags: django, database, django-models, filter

I'm trying to filter case-insensitive on the auth_user model which has a oneToOne relation with my model as shown in code beneath.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.TextField(max_length=120, null=True)
```

Normally to filter case-insensitive '__icontains' does the job, however if I filter with the following code, it is still case-sensitive even though I used icontains.

```
profiles = profiles.filter(Q(user__first_name__icontains=search) |
                               Q(user__last_name__icontains=search)).order_by('-id')
```

I think the problem is with using 'user__first_name' since it is a field of a module related to profile and filtering on 'headline' which is a direct field of profile can be done case-insensitive.

Any idea what the best solution is for this problem?

Comment: THis is likely a problem with the collation of your database: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html  the above should work with proper collation.

Comment: The icontains filter works on all other models in the database though. If it really is a problem with the collation of the database shouldn't it never allow case-insensitive searching?

Comment: but collation can be defined per column. See for example here: https://database.guide/how-to-set-the-character-set-and-collation-of-a-column-in-mysql/ you can inspect this in the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The column indeed had a different collation and after changing it it works just fine :)